# Access and read data from multiple *.resx files

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I am new to C# .NET.

I need to access *.resx files from my local folder and then retrieve data from each *.resx files.
I am creating a windows application for that.

So first, once I give path to that folder, it found the files there, but now, how can I read those file and get data from them to a temporary database on RAM.

private void buttonBrowseSource1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
        FolderBrowserDialog selectPathDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (selectPathDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(selectPathDialog.SelectedPath);
            FileInfo[] RESXFiles = di.GetFiles("*.resx");

            if (RESXFiles.Length == 0)
            {

                UpdateStatus("No RESX files found in this directory. Please check the folder/path again.");
            }
            else
            {

                UpdateStatus("Total " + RESXFiles.Length + " RESX files found in this directory.);
                textBoxSource1.Text = selectPathDialog.SelectedPath;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            UpdateStatus("Missing directory! Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: 'UpdateStatus' is the rich text box on Form just to show status messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ResXResourceReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) for this.

Comment: I tried that...I was creating a new class for handling the files but got an exception that the path is inaccessible. I tried everything all files are unlocked. May be there is something wrong with the class I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets the value of associated with key "MyKey" from the local resource file for a given culture ("~/MyPage.aspx.en.resx") or from the default one ("~/MyPage.aspx.resx")
object keyValue = HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/MyPage.aspx", "MyKey", culture);
```

use something like this

for windows this link may useful for you

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/handle-resource-files-read-and-write-into-a-resx-file-programmatically-part-iii/

Comment: may i help you more , is it useful for you

Comment: Thanks but not really helping....
I am creating windows application, where I need to get different resx files and merge data from them to create new resx files.